# Can you change the ConnectionString configuration value at runtime?

Tags: .net, sql

Is it possible to change the ConnectionString value in a app.config at runtime? According to [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.connectionstring.aspx) it should be possible as the ConnectionString property "Gets or sets the connection string."

My code looks like this:

```
ConnectionStringSettings mainConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mainConnection"];
mainConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=" + NewDatabaseName + ";Integrated Security=True";
```

The error that I receive is this: "Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration is read only."

Comment: Could you explain why you would want to switch the Database/connection string at run time ?.

Comment: I'm migrating content from an old version of a library to a new version of the library- both versions use the same connection string name but I want to read from one database and write to another database.

Comment: I just realized I wrote web.config in my post, I meant app.config (updated to reflect the change).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Configuration myConfiguration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~"); 
    myConfiguration.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("myDatabaseName").ConnectionString = txtConnectionString.Text; 
    myConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("myKey").Value = txtmyKey.Text; 
    myConfiguration.Save();
```

Ref: http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Modify-Web.Config-Run-Time.aspx

Comment: +1: just a small modification: if you want to re-read the new value from the config file again without the need to restart the application, refresh the file after saving it by calling the following:

*System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");*

Comment: This worked, although I was in a console application so I had to use a different line: 
Configuration myConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exeFilePath);
Note that this does change the physical configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you would want to constantly change your web.config at runtime (not recommended), but look here for some more information.

[Writing to .NET Web.config](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/blog/archive/2004/07/13/879.aspx)

The main thing here is that your web.config needs to have read and write permissons for the account that the ASPNET process is running as.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. You provided a recommendation stating that this is not good practice, and also provided further reading on the problem the OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

The connectionStrings-Section is readonly.
I need to change only during session, e.g. database-query with a read-only-account and after validation update/modify-operations with a granted account.
So my solution is a connectionString at appSettings-Section, which can be modified during runtime.
In Web.config:
    `<appSettings>
        <add key="dbconnectionstr" value="Database=...;Host=...;Password=...;Username=..."/>
    </appSettings>`
At SQLDataSource:
    `<asp:SqlDataSource ID="datasource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ AppSettings:dbconnectionstr %>" .... </asp:SqlDataSource>`
And at Code:
    `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnectionstr"] = newonnectionString;`

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing what you are seeing is a Compiler error, and not a run time error. The class you are using is a generated method from your application settings, and the generated properties only have a getter on the property, and no setter. That's why you receive that error.

To change the property, you need to use the Configuration class, and use the AppSettings property, passing in the string for the key.  Then you can call the Configuration.Save method.

Comment: It's a ConnectionStringSetting, not an AppSetting, and it's definitely not a compile error. What's weird is that the documentation says that I can *set* the value.

Answer (score -1):

Changing the connection string using the web.config at runtime is not recommended.
I would suggest maintaining these connections in a different file and implementing a filewatcher to verify if the value of these parameters have changed.